# Graphql mutations without input args did't work

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I created a NestJS sample, I add a `Mutation` to sync user info to my backend.

And added the following codes, the @GqlUser is to extract user info from my jwt token.

```js
  @Mutation((returns) => UpdateUserResult)
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  updateUser(@GqlUser() user: UserPrincipal): Observable<UpdateUserResult> {
    console.log('gql user:', user);
    const { userId, email, name } = user;
    return this.usersService.update({ id: userId, email, name }).pipe(
      map((b) => ({
        success: b,
      })),
    );
  }
```

The related GraphQL definition is generated by NestJS as the following:

```
type Mutation {
  //... other defs.
  updateUser: UpdateUserResult!
}


type UpdateUserResult {
  message: String!
  success: Boolean!
}

// other defs.
```

But when executing this mutation by the following forms.

```
// failed due to *the expectedName is not a ")"*, it is a syntax error
mutation SyncUser{
   updateUser(){//error
       success
   }
}
// or 
mutation SyncUser(){ // error 
   updateUser(){
       success
   }
}
```

or

```
// failed due to *this.subQuery is not a function*
mutation {
    updateUser {
       success
   }
}
```

[image]

In GraphQLspec, the input arguments should be optional in a mutation definition.

Comment: no args => no parentheses, of course

Comment: Can you post the implemenetation of usersService.update() also?

Answer (score -1):

Your `mutation` name is `updateUser`, so you should use something similar this:

```
mutation {
    updateUser () 
    {
       success    
    } 
          }
```

Consider that inside the parentheses, you need to pass data needed for the operation.

Anyway, I suggest using GraphQL PlayGround to find the correct query format.

Comment: I tried it in playground and attached an image. Not sure who downvote this.